# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Cardano has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Matthias Sieber]

[image: gRebel]

[image: Marek Mahut - StakeNuts]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4836011528945664).

Comment: Conflagrations to the new moderators. Great beginning.

Comment: This wouldn't have have happened without you @raghu, the community owes you a debt of gratitude for proposing and getting this site started.  So, thank you from all of us.  I think you are one of Cardano's many heroes.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to a completely new world of Moderation.

Congratulations for Matthias Sieber, gRebel, Marek Mahut - StakeNuts.

I am happy that we have elected new awesome moderators on Cardano Stack Exchange.

Wish you all luck and thank you for moderating. :)